# How to start writing an expression evaluator using LPEG in Lua?

Tags: lua, eval, lpeg

For example, I pass an expression string and a context table and it return a boolean value whether it was true/false. Can I do this using LPEG?

Something similar to this:

```
context = {
  x = 3,
  y = 3
}
local result = eval("x==y", context)
```

Comment: As I recall, that's how [Moonscript operates](https://github.com/leafo/moonscript/blob/master/moonscript/parse.moon)

Answer (score 2):

You can write an LPeg grammar that parses the expression into AST, and your eval function reads the AST and evaluates it using the context. See [lpeg.re doc](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/lpeg/re.html) for how to get an AST using LPeg.